# Turn specific string into link?

Tags: php, html

I am looking for a php way to search for a string of text and turn the text within that string to a link.

```
n being numbers 1-9
Jnn:nn:nn:nn
```

The link bit would look like this

```
<a href='http://juno.astroempires.com/map.aspx?loc=Jnn:nn:nn:nn'>Jnn:nn:nn:nn</a>
```

Hope this makes sense. I know its possible but I don't know how to do it.

---

This is the final solution I came up with because I integrated into an existing function, thanks for the idea tho bumperbox and the edit Tobiask

```
function makeClickableLinks($text){
    $text = html_entity_decode($text);
    $text = " ".$text;
    $text = eregi_replace('(((f|ht){1}tp://)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]+)',
            '<a href="\\1" target=_blank>\\1</a>', $text);
    $text = eregi_replace('(((f|ht){1}tps://)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]+)',
            '<a href="\\1" target=_blank>\\1</a>', $text);
    $text = eregi_replace('([[:space:]()[{}])(www.[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]+)',
            '\\1<a href="http://\\2" target=_blank>\\2</a>', $text);
    $text = eregi_replace('([_\.0-9a-z-]+@([0-9a-z][0-9a-z-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,3})',
            '<a href="mailto:\\1" target=_blank>\\1</a>', $text);
    $text = eregi_replace('(J[0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})',
            '<a href="http://juno.astroempires.com/map.aspx?loc=\\1:\\2:\\3:\\4" target=_blank>\\1:\\2:\\3:\\4</a>', $text);
    return $text;
}
```

This is used in a ajax / mysql chat system. I did have this done by jQuery but its less for the user to do if I just store the links.

Comment: `Hope this makes sense` no. add some example FROM -> TO

Comment: @genesis φ
Sorry for the slow reply just checked back, Well you can send anything like.

$string = "words with some other shit www.link.com also here is somthing stupid like J50:45:23:23";

So when you send that srting to the function like makeClickableLinks($string)

It will change the original to:
"words with some other shit <a href='www.link.com'>www.link.com</a> also here is somthing stupid like <a href='http://juno.astroempires.com/map.aspx?loc=J50:45:23:23'>J50:45:23:23</a>

I hope that makes sense genesis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look at preg_replace

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

i haven't tested this but it should be pretty close

```
$str = preg_replace("/(J\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})/s", "<a href="{$1}">{$1}</a>", $str);
```

\d matches a digit
{2} means 2 digits

{$1} = everything that was matched inside the first set of ( )

Answer (score 1):

using the regex engine is totally overkill for that. Why not try something like this:

```
$url_base   = 'http://juno.astroempires.com/map.aspx';
$loc        = 'Jnn:nn:nn:nn';
$parameters = array('loc' => $loc);

$url = sprintf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', $url_base.'?'.http_build_query($parameters), $loc);

// do whatever you need with $url
echo $url;
```